# Free Jquery website templates

Tags: jquery-ui

Is there any site that offers free jqueryUI templates / demos on jqueryUI being used in Websites. I am a java developer who is working on a web application and know very little about jquery. Going through tutorials is tedious and i prefer learning by examples.

NB: I don't require the whole of jquery, just to add spice to the UI.

So please let me know if there is any such resource as mentioned above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demos themselves are the best resource IMO, [check out the demos section of the jQuery UI site here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/).

In each demo, [let's take for example the dialog demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) there's a **View Source** link with direct code for the example.  Also above the demo there's a **New Window** link to open that sample in a new window to see *only* that example in action, not the rest of the site, [here's what the dialog demo looks like by itself](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/default.html).

Comment: Actually I went through this site before. But what i actually want is.. well call it "spoon feeding", some place where I get ready made templates which use jquery. Something like this site: http://blog.templatemonster.com/2010/03/30/jquery-templates-top-picks/ . @Nick: Could you post some similar sites that are "free"?

Comment: @Anand - There's a few examples out there, for example: http://blarnee.com/wp/20-new-examples-of-advanced-jquery-uis-in-action/ , a much broader jQuery centric site but has *many* that use jQuery UI as well is: http://jquerystyle.com/

Comment: @NickCraver the links to the two site you have suggested no longer work. The blog.templatemonster.com suggest by Anand is awesome. I going try to "copy" one or two of them shortly.